# QTableView- overriding CSS in QAbstractTableModel

Tags: qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I am using commmon css for our product which has templates for QTableView as below

```
QTableView::item
{
    padding-left:10px;
    height:40px;
    width:80px;
    color: #5a5a5a;
    border-bottom :1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

In one case, I want to change the text color of QTableView as red. I am doing it by following code in data function of QAbstractTableModel

```
if (role == Qt::TextColorRole || role == Qt::ForegroundRole)
    {
        QColor color(Qt::red);
        QBrush brush (color);
        brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
        return brush;
    }
```

But, color of the text is not changing, it is taking color from the CSS.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following for `textcolor` changes in what is essentially `QSqlTableModel`, sub classed to `CustomSqlTableModel` to allow for overriding `setData()` and submit, and also to add a custom refresh function.  The following should work just the same for `QAbstractItemModel` instances:

```
QVariant ExampleSqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role) const
{
  if (role == Qt::ForegroundRole)
  {
    QColor color;
    // Only the display names need to be coloured.
    if(idx.column() == 1)
    {
      int value = CustomSqlTableModel::data(1, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
      switch(value)
      {
        case 0:         color = QColor(Qt::yellow); break; 
        case 1:         // same as 2
        case 2:         color = QColor(Qt::blue);   break; 
        case 3:         color = QColor(Qt::green);  break; 
        case 4:         // same as 5
        case 5:         color = QColor(Qt::red);    break; 
        default:        color = QColor(Qt::black);  break; 
      }
    }
    return QVariant(color);
  }
  return CustomSqlTableModel::data(idx,role);
}
```

I would also advise being a bit more specific with your widgets.  Subclass all the `QTableView` instances that you do want your `stylesheet` to affect, and don't apply a general `stylesheet` to `QTableView` if it is going to affect the text color.

That way, if all other `QTableViews` have been sub classed to be `myAwesomeTableView`, then you could replace your `stylesheet` content to be:

```
myAwesomeTableView::item
{
    padding-left:10px;
    height:40px;
    width:80px;
    color: #5a5a5a;
    border-bottom :1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

If you always want the other `QTableView` to have red text, rather define a second subclass, and handle it via `stylesheet` instead of implementing it in code like I did.  I needed different rows to have different text colors on a single column based on the value in that column.  To do it via `stylesheet`, make another `QTableView` subclass, for argument, `myOtherAwesomeTableView`, and implement `stylesheet` as follows:

```
myOtherAwesomeTableView::item
{
    padding-left:10px;
    height:40px;
    width:80px;
    color: #ff0000;
    border-bottom :1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
```

Let me know if this helps you...

Comment: Hitsugaya198: Thanks for your reply. displaying text color in red is based on conditions, so, I can't make the changes in style sheet. I want my table to look same as my all other table (which has a css applied to it) in normal case, but, in some condition I want to show text in red color. I tried returning red color as QVariant from data function. but, that doesn't seem to work. Even I tried changing the object name for table and apply a different stylesheet which does not have color in it, but in that case, color gets inherited from parent table. Is there any other way to override it?

Comment: I think, first split it from the stylesheet (or temporarily remove the color element from the stylesheet).  If that doesn't work, try calling the following two lines from within a subclassed QTableView:

    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish( this );

I do that for textboxes, spinboxes and tableviews that require runtime colour changes.

To be clear, subclass this one tableview, and make the colour change a function of the view.  when you the view is refreshed (when the AbstractTableView fires dataChanged or modelReset signals, call the above lines.

Comment: returning color as Qvariant works when color element is not there in stylesheet, But, my requirement is to use stylesheet and override the color in some condition.

Comment: I have another idea, but it's too much text to fit in a comment.  Try this collabedit link.  [CollabEdit](http://collabedit.com/cqbuh) Will chat to you there.